# Spring @Autowired in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, autowired

I have one problem with @Autowire annotation in my Kotlin code.
There is one piece of code that works perfectly

```
@Controller
open class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var autowiredBean: AutowiredBean

    @RequestMapping(value = "/SomePage", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    fun somePage(@RequestParam("param") param: Int): ModelAndView {
        // some code
    }
}
```

But after adding some security checking, @Autowire annotation stops working

```
@Controller
open class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var autowiredBean: AutowiredBean

    @RequestMapping(value = "/SomePage", method =       arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('MODULE', 'FINANCE')")
    fun somePage(@RequestParam("param") param: Int): ModelAndView {
        // some code
    }

}
```

It's just doesn't initialize. I tried to initialize it by my controller constructor but had got the same result. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What error exactly you got, or what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: NO error. My autowiredBean equals null in second piece of code. Seems that Spring doesn't inject it.

Comment: If it null - this mean that spring doesn't create this bean at all. Please show us how you using `PaymentController`.

Comment: Mark `fun somePage(@RequestParam("param") param: Int): ModelAndView` as an open function.

Comment: YES!! It works. Thank you very much. I thought that if you have open class then all functions inside are also open. My bad.